# Seek 14" laptop, touchpad, buttons, Synaptics Touchpad, & trial-able before decision

Tags: laptop

I have posted an early version of this question and vetted options [elsewhere](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/14-laptop-average-performance-touchpad-buttons.831080/#post-10969106).  I am seeking a laptop with requirements that are hard to fulfill are:

- Real touchpad, not clickpad with depressable corners
- Real touchpad buttons
- Synaptics Touchpad driver software
- No nub (pointer stick in middle of keyboard)
- 14" monitor at 1366x768 resolution so that things aren't too tiny
- Not Lenovo
- Have to physcially try in Ottawa/Toronto (Canada) before buying

The less difficult requirements are:

- Windows 10 64-bit(need home, will accept pro, but not needed)
- 256GB SSD or 512GB HDD (more OK, but won't be used)
- Fairly recent i5 processor

For the last point of the first list, physical trialling ensures that keyboard layout doesn't seem awkward, good registration and natural feel of key presses, good registration of contact with touchpad, natural feel of pointer tracking (not like you're controlling the pointer with wet noodle).  Sometimes, key registration is so unpredicatble that I'm hammering away at them like a kung fu master just to get predictable behaviour, which is critical for extensive use of combinations of hotkeys (for example, in vim text editor).  And sloppy pointer tracking just makes me end up clicking the wrong things, sometimes disastorously (Unless. I. Go. Very. Maddeningly. Slowly).

The need for buttons and Synaptics is to get middle-mouse click-and-drag, which is not possible with Windows 10's 3-finger tap.  Synaptics lets me turn the left button into a middle button.  Left button actions can be done using only the touchpad by enabling "Tap again and hold to drag" and "Locking Drags".

The following alternatives are not viable:

- A clickpad is a deal breaker because click-and-drag requires keeping a finger on the touchpad while moving another finger to the depressable corner, which causes the pointer to move (unwantedly)
- Dragging around a mouse is a deal breaker because I often don't have the surface space or I'm rushing off somewhere and don't have the luxury to look for and bring accessories
- I don't consider ordering and returning laptops as a practical way to try them out, even if such a policy is allowed as a matter of legal requirement.

In the short list that I link to above, I think I'm focusing on options #02 and #03.  I'm really not sure what the difference is.  From a few weekends of visiting brick-and-mortar stores, trying to find something that was selected from online research is impossible.  Yet the selections on display do not fulfill the difficult requirements above.

**UPDATE:** To break my current impasse, I revisited some brick & mortar establishments. I believe that focusing only on the requirements of 14" display + touchpad buttons moves the otherwise impossible combination of requirements into the realm of the possible.  I can then vet away by brand, and if it doesn't have Synaptics, I can look up the manufacturer site for Synaptics drivers.  In my mind, there doesn't seem to be much point in contacting Synaptics, as each manufacturer needs to customize the drivers for their laptop models.  I got this guidance from helpful staff at one of the stores, just as it was closing, so I will need to see how well it works next weekend.

**UPDATE**  The above strategy of looking only for 14" display models with buttons brought me up against a wall quite quickly.  It's a good thing that I stuck to the requirement of physically trialing the laptop before buying.  The models I found were low end, with unacceptable touchpad response and/or general computer response.  The pointer moves even as I try to lift my finger, and many seconds passed after typing before letters showed up, despite being lightly loaded.  My experience thus far is that the higher end (over $500 Canadian) gives acceptable response, though there is still a lot of subjective variability.

Since I have to migrate away from Windows 7 soon, and away from semi-functional laptop on which it resides, I had to loosen the criteria and admit other options.  Forgoing buttons+Synaptics and relying on a wireless mouse seemed too much, considering various scenario.  Expanding the size criteria to include 13" to 15" admitted some good HP options, and maybe others (I only got a short ways in my search after giving up on the 14" criterion).

I had interesting discussion with the now-familiar staff:

**Considerations in performance and future proofing**

- Don't future proof beyond 3-5 years, as quality of parts are poorer these days (my aim was 8 years)
- The more compact design also means more heat, which doesn't help
- Drives are not upgradable on some models, e.g, to move to SSD
- Memory is not expandable on most models
- Future proofing means checking for upgradability or immediately going for SSD and more than 8GB RAM if possible
- The more advance heads up of HDD degredation is of limited use if one doesn't regularly perform [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) checks (though I still find it reassuring to have that diagnostic option for when I run into strange situations)
- If I still hope the laptop will last 8 years, then at least go for i5 8th generation, if not 10th
- Interestingly, the number of cores can vary even within the same generation (most 10th gen have 4 cores while most 8th gen have 6)
- One of the low end 14" with buttons had a 4GB RAM and Win 10 running in "S" mode, reducing capabilty and processor demand and making it more on par with smartphones
- The other low end 14" with poor performance had a Ryzen 3.  At least for low integer values "n", Ryzen "n" equates extremely roughly in performance to Intel i"n"
- Also interestingly, AMD is killing it in the desktop market, but is still struggling in the laptop market due to thermal throttling of it's clock

Comment: What you already do it's pretty much all you can do. [Related comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1504288/key-travel-on-thinkpad-x201#comment2272666_1504288). I don't choose laptops by keyboards and if you don't like the keyboard just bring another on the backpack. It's not such a big deal.

Comment: For me, it is a very big deal.  I often don't have surface space.

Comment: If you have a look at the related comment, that's mostly true so without ordering or going to the shop and check it out it will be hard.

Comment: Understood.  That's what I'm trying to contend with.  I just wanted to clarify that you initial comment is highly dependent on the individual.  If it wasn't a big deal, one wouldn't go to extreme lengths to find a solution.

Comment: I agree, you didn't mention you don't want an external keyboard either. You can ask around on forums so if someone has the same laptop could measure it somehow (btw, this isn't the place for that nor we allow discussions here) and look for reviews. I'm afraid I can't help you more than this.

Comment: Pretty well, you answered the question with your first comment.  There is no solution.  Or perhaps the solution is your last comment, to ask on forums.  Unfortunately, I've tried this with other specific models at the outset of my search weeks ago.  No response.  Possibly because there are so many variations on a model (some being sold by specific vendors) that the chances of someone seeing my post are slim.  Actually, even if they respond, it's not the same as me trialling the laptop.  So no solution.  Hoping that's not the case...

Comment: Please add a country tag as this depends on local laws. In Poland for example you can return any online order in two weeks without giving any reason. AFAIK many EU countries have similar regulations (or was it an EU law?)

Comment: @user2153235 more often than not all models in series will have the same build, so you don't need to search by a part number. If you want to buy, say, a Latitude e7490 you don't need to hit that specific model as they will all likely have the same keyboard.

Comment: I added the country, but my concern is that it isn't a practical way to try laptops even if the option to return it is required by law. About different models in a series having the same build, sometimes the names get very weird, such as in the list that I link to in the question. I'm never sure when I can assume that models with similar names have the same build. In my web search over the past few weeks, I've seen models with similar names, and I thought I could assume a similar build, but they differed in display size. It's important enough that I want to be sure.

Comment: The problem is that, in a real store, it can be hard to find *the* laptop that you converged upon online. I've been wandering stores for a few weekends (when I have time) and none of them meet the physical interface needs. The few options with touchpads+buttons don't meet the other form factor requirements..  As for a product lasting a decade, I do admit, it's bucking the trend. But my last 2 laptops have fared well in this way. It's in hibernation most times. Also, my performance needs are modest, which makes future-proofing automatic.

Comment: @user2153235, *" it can be hard to find the laptop that you converged upon online"* -- You're setting yourself up to be disappointed by searching for models online and then trying to find them in stores. A walk-in laptop retailer can only stock a fraction of the models you can find online, and the models you see online tend to be exclusive to online orders! You have to use only the website for the store you plan to go to, and check their stock ahead of going if you have to browse online.

Comment: I fully agree. I started with the strategy that you described. I forgot what all the challenges were -- perhaps the search facilities -- the fields didn't allow me to specify what I wanted, or the disparities in the data returned, or just lack of the relevant details. It may also have been that they can only stock a fraction of what they show online as well. In the end, I gave up and visited real stores. My criteria are so confining that the chances of finding a display model is low.  Touchpad+buttons, synaptics, 14", not Lenovo, etc.

Comment: Maybe you should post a question here directly asking for actual laptop recommendations. Make sure to tag `Canada` and express all of the hardware specs you are looking for. Looking back at the original question, I didn't see you explain *what* you're looking for, so this question might not be on-topic for this site anyways.

Comment: Just so that I'm clear on this suggestion, are you saying that respondents would know what's on display in bricks-and-mortar stores in my town?  My big challenge now is to physically try out the laptop before deciding.

Comment: To be fair, it's not *just* about how to do X.  X is how to confirm that identified laptop options are acceptable.  Either someone has a method to share or they don't.  That's not opinion.

Comment: @Romen: Any laptop hardware suggestion might not lead to a concrete decision and will go out of date quickly.

Comment: @user2153235, That is still considered [on-topic](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Where this question is asking for general advice, not for specific laptop recommendations. Please consider re-framing your problem as a question asking for laptop recommendations. That would absolutely be on topic, and you can add *"I must be able to try a suggested laptop before I buy it"* as one of your requirements.