# Acer TravelMate P2410 or P648-MG?

Tags: laptop

I think I've converged on a laptop that meets the following criteria, adapted from
[Seek 14" laptop, touchpad, buttons, Synaptics Touchpad, & trial-able before decision](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/seek-14-laptop-touchpad-buttons-synaptics-touchpad-trial-able-before-deci)

- Brand: Not Lenova nor Dell Latitude (possibly others - prefer not to discuss brand criteria)
- OS: Windows 10 64-bit, home or pro
- Processor type: i5, 8th generation (4 cores or  more)
- Screen size: 14"
- Memory: 8GB and up
- 256GB SSD or 512GB HDD
- Fixed (unmoving) touchpad with 2 separate buttons beneath it + Synaptics drivers
- Not 1-piece clickpad with depressable corners
- Preferably no pointing stick, but might be tolerable
- Future-proof for 8 years for modest usage (browsing, Microsoft Office, Cywin, Netflix)

### Option #1

- Acer TravelMate P2 P2410-G2-M variants NX.VGTAA.005, NX.VGTAA.006
- NX.VGTAA.006 TMP2410-G2-M-55HN 14" Notebook - 1366 x 768 - Core i5 i5-8250U - 8 GB RAM - 500 GB HDD - Windows 10 Pro 64-bit - Intel UHD Graphics 620 - ComfyView - English Keyboard - Bluetooth
- NX.VGTAA.005 has additional French Keyboard Localization
- Info pages:

  - https://www.pc-canada.com/item/NX%2EVGTAA%2E005.html
  - https://www.pc-canada.com/item/NX%2EVGTAA%2E006.html
  - https://www.cdw.ca/product/acer-tra...re-i5-8250u-8-gb-ram-500-gb-h/5280305?pfm=srh
- Old model review https://www.channelpronetwork.com/review/review-acer-travelmate-p2-goldilocks-performance
- Touchpad + buttons, Synaptics at https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/767?b=1

  - Top view at https://www.acer.com/ac/en/CA/content/professional-model/NX.VGTAA.005

    - https://static.acer.com/up/Resource/Acer/Professional/Product/Notebook/TravelMate%20P2/Photo%20Gallery/20180213/TravelMate-P2410_gallery_05.png
  - Top view at https://www.cdw.ca/product/acer-travelmate-p2410-g2-m-55hn-14in-core-i5-8250u-8-gb-ram-500-gb-h/5280305

    - https://webobjects2.cdw.com/is/image/CDW/5280305c?wid=1142&hei=818&resMode=bilin&fit=fit,1

### Option #2

- Acer TravelMate P648-MG TMP648-MG-746N Notebook 14" FHD IPS ComfyView, Intel Core i7-6500U Dual-core (2.50 GHz), 8GB DDR4, 256GB SSD NVIDIA GeForce 940M 2GB, Win7 Pro Upgradable to Win10 Pro (64-bit)
- Manufactcurer number NX.VCWAA.003
- Info: https://www.canadacomputers.com/product_info.php?cPath=664_1524&item_id=119426
- Touchpad + buttons, no nub, Synaptics: https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/6693?b=1
- Doesn't have 4+ core i5, does i7 make up for computational horse power?

### Questions

(1) In view of my criteria, can anyone provide considerations to ponder in choosing between these two?

(2) Acer is Taiwanese, but in which country are Acer TravelMates made?

(3) For those who have owned/used one/both of these models, how do you find the touchpad regristration of contact and tracking of finger movement?  No false contact from nearness of hand, and pointer tracking feels natural rather than erratic?

(4) An IT support colleague said that laptops upgraded from Windows 7 to 10 will be missing drivers. If a laptop's specification say Windows 10, does that mean it Windows 10 was installed from scratch?

Comment: In regards to 4) OEMs do not often sell an upgraded install, it's normally a full install from scratch. Keep in mind that refurbished or recertified PCs are not always from the OEM, and may not have the official factory image pre-installed (it could be an upgraded or modified install). Also, many Windows 7 laptops will upgrade to Windows 10 with no problems at all since Windows 10 includes "Plug & Play" generic drivers for all sorts of components like WiFi, USB controllers, trackpads, etc.

Comment: Also, I regret to inform you that Canada Computers will most likely not be able to fulfill an order your Option #2. It is marked as clearance, sold out at all stores, and the last two "Open Box" inventory in the company are likely demo models that will not be shipped to another store without a deposit. They may not be in saleable condition either... Hopefully that model is available at another retailer.

Comment: Thanks, Romen.  You may have just simplified the entire situation1